# What should do with 'make pycaffe' error?

Tags: python, macos, caffe

When I run `make pycaffe` on Mac. The following error:

```
 CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
...
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lboost_python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

It looks like no lboost_python.But I have added its addr in the Makefile.config

Comment: I almost try all the methods i can find on Web.

Comment: In the error it says, `library not found for -lboost_python`. Install that library for linker.

Comment: Did you run `brew install --build-from-source -vd boost-python` ? What does `brew list boost-python` tell?